# Characterization of degree sequence of a forest

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

One problem in *Graph Theory: An Introductory course* by Bollobas asks to characterize the degree sequence of a forest.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Yuval gave you very good advice, I only want to add that drawing lots of examples is usually a great starting point, in particular both positive examples (forrests) and negative (non-forrests).

Answer (score 3):

A good idea would be to understand the situation for trees, for which see [here](http://exwiki.org/mw/index.php?title=A_characterization_of_the_degree_sequence_of_a_tree). The obvious conjecture would be that any sequence which sums to an even number smaller than $2n$ is the degree sequence of a forest. (That's not saying that the conjecture is necessarily true.)